# Angular Controller called twice

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've tried using both the DOM and the stateProvider methods.

**Feed.html**

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="panel panel-card" ng-repeat="post in posts" class="col-lg-12 fadeInUp animated" style="-webkit-animation-delay: {{$index * 0.1}}s; animation-delay: {{$index * 0.1}}s;">
            <div class="panel-body bg-primary">{{post.user_id}} from {{post.squad_id}}</div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**feed.controller.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .controller('FeedController', FeedController);

    FeedController.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function FeedController($scope) {
        console.log($scope);
    }

})();
```

**routes.config.js**

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(routesConfig);

    routesConfig.$inject = ['$locationProvider', '$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'RouteProvider'];
    function routesConfig($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, Route) {

      // use the HTML5 History API
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

      // Default route
      //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/feed');

      // Application Routes States
      $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
          url: '',
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: Route.base('app.html'),
          resolve: {
            _assets: Route.require('icons', 'toaster', 'animate')
          }
        })
        .state('app.feed', {
          url: '/feed/',
          templateUrl: Route.base('feed.html'),
          controller: "FeedController",
          resolve: {}
        })
    }

})();
```

The other way was to insert `ng-controller="FeedController"` into the top div in `feed.html` and comment out `controller: "FeedController",` from `routes.config.js`

**app.html**

```
<!-- top navbar-->
<header ng-include="'templates/top-navbar.html'" ng-class="app.theme.topbar"></header>
<!-- Sidebar-->
<aside ng-include="'templates/sidebar.html'" ng-class="app.theme.sidebar"></aside>
<!-- Main-->
<section>
   <!-- Content-->
   <div ui-view="" autoscroll="false" ng-class="app.views.animation" class="app"></div>
</section>
<!-- Page footer-->
<footer ng-include="'templates/footer.html'"></footer>
```

Both of these methods console.log($scope) twice with different $id's. This happens on page reload and state change.

Anyone have any idea's?

Comment: I think you wrap you body with `FeedController` only..

Comment: What is `RouteProvider`?

Comment: How many feeds do you have at your page?

Comment: [RouteProvider](http://pastebin.com/kPSATENw)

Comment: There is only 1 feed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not where I can test this, but you might try just commenting out the `.controller('FeedController', FeedController);` line in `feed.controller.js`.

I think hitting the route will fire off the controller, so you don't need to fire it off there.

Comment: That's what defines the controller in the app. Otherwise, I get `[ng:areq] Argument 'FeedController' is not a function, got undefined` **edit:** I should add that that error happened twice.

Comment: hmmm, well maybe it is the call to `angular.module` - you do that twice. not  sure how it works, but I always set that to a variable and use it:  `var app = angular.module('app');  app.controller...  and app.config...`

Comment: Just replaced all occurrences of angular.module("app") with app. Still happening.

Comment: Is `feed.html` injected into `app.html`? can we see the contents of `app.html`?

Comment: What is the purpose of `class="app"` in `<div ui-view="" autoscroll="false" ng-class="app.views.animation" class="app"></div>`?  Could this be firing the controller twice? I don't know your entire architecture, but it seems the issue is created elsewhere. I'm basically shooting in the dark!

Comment: .app is just some css that is applied to that element. ng-class="app.views.animation" is a var in the app that sets the animation css class.

Comment: i'm at a loss. I would dig through the stack trace. You know about `console.trace()` right?

Comment: Yep. One is originating from requestLoaded and the other from completeOutstandingRequest

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to this occur. But, i suspect url sub state. Try removing the last bar.

Comment: What do you mean by last bar?

Comment: url: '/feed/', but url: '/feed' is sufficient

Comment: Adding the slash was a fix I read on another SO thread. It's inconsequential.

Comment: Well.. Your controller was instantiated two times. And no has many ways to instantiate they. Your code is correct, but, this "solution" is strange. Try naming your controller with "controller as ctrlTest" and observes your scope.